# Vuejs nuxtjs Store update not getting reflected in the middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am new to VueJs and I tried to create a small application using `nuxtJS` where I have a login page and a home page. I am using middleware `authjs` to check if the user is authenticated to view the `home` page.

The vuex store contains a flag `isLoggedIn` to store the user's logged-in state. The issue I'm facing here is:

When I update the store from the `login` page(using commit function) and redirect to the `home` page, the store update is `not reflected in the middleware` which is called before the home page and I'm going back to the login page.

/pages/login.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <default-header />
    <login-form :onSubmit="onSubmit" />
  </div>
</template>

export default {

  methods: {
    async onSubmit(){
      //fetching some data, skipped here for simplicity
      this.$store.commit('marklogin')
      this.$router.push('home')
    }
 }
 
}
```

/store/index.js

```js
 export const state = () => ({
    loggedin: false
  })
  
  export const mutations = {
    marklogin(state) {
      state.loggedin = true
    }
  }
```

/middleware/auth.js

```js
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (!store.state.loggedin) {
      return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

This is /pages/home.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <default-header />
    <videos :videos="videos.data"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      videos: []
    };
  },
  async fetch() {
      this.videos = await fetch(
        'http://localhost:8080/videos'
      ).then(res => res.json());
    },
  middleware: 'auth'
}
</script>
```

/components/Login.vue

```js
<template>
    <div class="container-form">
        <h2>User Login</h2>
    <b-form>
        <b-form-group
        id="input-group-1"
        label-for="input-1"
        >
        <b-form-input
            id="input-1"
            v-model="form.username"
            type="text"
            required
            :state="usernameValidation"
            aria-describedby="input-live-help input-live-feedback"
            placeholder="Enter your user name"
        ></b-form-input>
        <b-form-invalid-feedback id="input-live-feedback">
            Enter at least 3 letters
        </b-form-invalid-feedback>
        </b-form-group>
        <b-form-checkbox
            id="checkbox-1"
            v-model="status"
            name="checkbox-1"
            value="accepted"
            class="remember-me-checkbox"
            >
            Remember me
        </b-form-checkbox>
    </b-form>
        <button type="button" @click="() => onSubmit(form.username)" class="login-button" variant="success">Login</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the authjs, the value of `store.state.loggedin` is coming as false. Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: you haven't shown how you are using `/middleware/auth.js`

Comment: Any reason why the submit is an `async` function?

Comment: @JaromandaX Added that

Comment: @painotpi I had removed a fetch call for simplicity. have added it as a comment now

Comment: Can you show the `login-form` component? my guess is that the form-submit triggers a page refresh which does not maintain the store.

Comment: This should not be an issue if you do basic client-side routing; I've setup a codesandbox with client-side routing and it works as expected - https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-grass-knw9h?file=/store/index.js

Comment: @painotpi You may be right. I have added the login-form component as well

Comment: What does `onSubmit` do on the login component? and arrow functions are usually discouraged with vue's object style syntax as it's easy to misplace the `this` context.

Comment: @painotpi onSubmit is defined in /pages/login.vue on top. Okay, but the functon works as expected in terms of data being passed.

Comment: Okay the way you've written and passing the function is not entirely accurate from a pattern/usage standpoint - you should be emitting an event from the child component and listening in the parent component instead of passing the whole function down to the child.

Comment: Okay, how about I write this function in the LoginForm component? Will that be right?

Comment: Would you mind doing a vscode pair programming for 5 minutes to help me understand this. I would be highly grateful

Comment: @AbhinavJain sure, let's connect over e-mail for now and figure the time, tarun.pai@outlook.com

Comment: @painotpi I have figured out the issue. Not sure how exactly it started working but it is working now

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. @painotpi

Comment: Cool, you're welcome!